# What does ドアの開け閉めの時に手を挟まれなり戸袋に手を引き込まれないようご注意下さい。mean?

Tags: expressions

Google translate gives: "Please be careful not to get your hands caught in the door opening and closing and pulling your hand into the door closet." but I'm very doubtful on the second part of the sentence. Wtf is a door closet in a train?

Thanks if anyone can answer this question!

Comment: I think you made a typo. It should probably be: ドアの開け閉めの時に手を挟まれ*たり*戸袋に手を引き込まれないようご注意下さい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we go by,

> ドアの開け閉めの時に手を挟まれたり戸袋に手を引き込まれないようご注意下さい。

It means:

> Please keep your hands away from the door so you do not get stuck when it is opening and closing.

"Door closet" could refer to 戸袋, which means when the door is open, you can get caught, like in the picture below:

[image: 戸袋]